# How to configure the scanner to scan more than one barcode at a time?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, barcode-scanner

I'm creating an app for a Zebra device and want to read more than one barcode at a time. I can not find the right configuration of the EMDK to achieve this.

I have find this link, but I can not find a way to set the value...

https://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/6-8/api/reference/com/symbol/emdk/barcode/ScannerConfig.ScanMode.html

Comment: Wouldn't it be helpful to consult the materials on this page or contact Zebra support? [MULTI-CODE DATA FORMATTING](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/scanning-systems/multi-code-data-formatting.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample from Zebra which shows how to do this: https://github.com/Zebra/samples-emdkforandroid-7_3/tree/master/MultiBarcodeSample1

The relevant code from that sample that configures multi-barcode is as follows:

```java
ScannerConfig config = scanner.getConfig();
// Scan Mode set to Multi Barcode
// If it is a imager
config.readerParams.readerSpecific.imagerSpecific.scanMode = ScannerConfig.ScanMode.MULTI_BARCODE;
// If it is a camera
config.readerParams.readerSpecific.cameraSpecific.scanMode = ScannerConfig.ScanMode.MULTI_BARCODE;
// Setting the barcode count
if(barcodeCount.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
  config.multiBarcodeParams.barcodeCount = Integer.parseInt(barcodeCount.getText().toString());
}
scanner.setConfig(config);
```